# UIAlertaction button text alignment bug?

Tags: ios, uiview, ios10, text-alignment, uialertaction

i have a problem with UIAlertAction text alignment , in IOS 10 when language isArabic .

sometimes the action sheet displayed in this way :
[image]

and some times it's displayed with this way:
[image]

this issue just with IOS 10, how could i set the textAlignmetCenter always ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used the following, for both aligning and styling the text of UIAlertControllers:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

let messageText = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: "The message you want to display",
    attributes: [
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody),
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()
    ]
)

myAlert.setValue(messageText, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

You can do a similar thing with the title, if you use `"attributedTitle"`, instead of `"attributedMessage"`